# Duplicate keys in component v-for loop

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

## v-for duplicate keys issue

This returns a list just fine, but when I modify a user inside the array, like user.role = 'something', it says that I have duplicate keys. The key is set with the user.id which is their firebase key, so duplication shouldn't be possible? The result is that the modified user takes over some other user in the list, so it shows up two times (I haven't tried with more than two users), but if I go back and then re-visit this list, it shows up as expected with the updated data.

V-for loop:

```
<ManageUsersListItem
  v-for="user in sortedUsers"
  :key="user.id"
  :user="user"
  @removeManager="removeManager(user)"
  @makeManager="makeManager(user)"
  @removeUser="removeUser(user)"
/>
```

Data:

```
data() {
  return {
    users: [],
  }
},
firestore() {
  return {
    users: db.collection('brands').doc(this.brand.id).collection("users")
  }
},
```

Sorting the array:

```
computed: {
  sortedUsers() {
    return this.users.sort(function(a,b) {
      var c = new Date(a.userAddedOn)
      var d = new Date(b.userAddedOn)
      return c-d
    })
  }
},
```

The method I use to change a users role:

```
methods: {
  makeManager(user) {
     this.$firestore.users.doc(user.id).update({
        role: 'admin'
     })
  },
},
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the content of the `sortedUsers` object?

Comment: Console logged it now, and that might actually be the problem.. It's an observer. I'm gonna try to return a proper array from firestore instead 

Comment: Confirmed... calling firestore manually and pushing to the data() users array worked perfectly fine @acdcjunior

Comment: Alrighty! Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

to avoid duplicate key use index instead of user.id

```
<ManageUsersListItem
 v-for="(user, index) in sortedUsers"
 :key="index"
 :user="user"
 @removeManager="removeManager(user)"
 @makeManager="makeManager(user)"
 @removeUser="removeUser(user)"
/>
```